# How to name an arraylist as a variable?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm wondering how would I make an arraylist be the name of a variable which is defined in the class somewhere else? like:

```
String list1 = "cheese";
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I tried that but it didn't work.

EDIT: I WANT TO NAME THE ARRAYLIST WHATEVER THE String list1 is.

Comment: Create your list as `ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();`

Comment: You want to assign variable `String list1` value of type `ArrayList`?

Comment: no, I want to set the name of the arraylist to whatever String list1 is.

Comment: Do you maybe need a hash table of strings (keys) and ArrayLists (values)?

Comment: What is it that you're attempting to accomplish?  Typically, when someone wants to name a collection the same as another variable, they want a key-map pair (i.e. `Map<String, List<String>>`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, because variable `list1` already has type `String` and you can't assign to this variable value of `ArrayList` type.

If you need new `ArrayList` with `list1` variable there, you need to create new variable, for example
`ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();`
and add `list1` to `list2` like this `list2.add(list1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set a variable name. I don´t know of any case where this would be possible, because you need a unique name (in special cases like creating variables among a method you can have several with the same name) for a variable to use it.

So the only way ist to use in a way @Alexander Podkutins suggestion:

```
 ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with fields since you cannot declare them twice. However, you can create a local vairable in a method with the same name.

## Fields

This will NOT WORK EVER because you create a variable called `list1` and you cannot create a second variable with the same name. No matter what the type is!

```
public class SomeClass {
    String list1;
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

## Local variables

However, you can create a local variable with the same name inside a method. This variable will overlay the original (the original will not be "deleted" or so, you can still access it with `this.list1`). **Note that this is considered a bad pratice, since it makes you code very hard to read.**

```
public class SomeClass {
    String list1;
    public void myMethod(){
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        // to get the original string do:
        this.list1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is statically typed, meaning that there are a specific set of data types an once a variable is initialized the data type can never be changed. On a side note, it is hard to understand what you want to accomplish?